# is there a way to pass js command to dev console while automating testcafe testcase

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, testcafe, browser-automation

This is the flow:

1. Open the homepage
2. Run the command on dev console
3. Continue with rest of the test steps

top.startTour("123", 0) is the command

I am writing an automation test case wherein i need to pass a specific command on chrome dev console to activate a plugin required for my test case. I am using testcafe framework for my tests.

there is an interface in java JavaScriptExecutor which is supported via selenium. I am trying to see if there is anything specific for testcafe which i could use

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: there is an interface in java JavaScriptExecutor which is supported via selenium. I am trying to see if there is anything specific for testcafe which i could use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried inject scripts into head tag

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts.html#access-dom-in-the-injected-scripts

this might help

Answer (score 3):

You can use [t.eval](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/eval.html) to create a one-time use client function and execute it in your tests. Is this solution applicable to your scenario?

Comment: so this is how i am trying to do.... test('Sample test case for Tour', async (t) => {
  //Log in
  await loginPage.login();

  //activate tour pop up
  this is where i need to add
});